# angular directive isolated scope property updated in link function but not reflecting on directive view

Tags: angularjs, scope, directive

I have a case where, I have a directive which get a value form Controller $scope.colorName. Directive bind it one-way and keep this value in isolated scope "colorVar". Template of directive render "colorVar" as {{ colorVar }} .
I need to change the value of "colorVar" in link function of directive. but its not reflecting on UI.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appCtrl">
{{colorName}}
    <my-directive color='{{colorName}}'>
    </my-directive>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('appCtrl',function($scope){
$scope.colorName='red';

})
.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            colorVar: '@color'
        },
        template: '<span> {{ colorVar }} </span><span>{{extra}}</span>',
        link:function(scope,element,attrs){
        scope.colorVar='orange';
        scope.extra='kk';

        }
    };
});
```

In Link function I have updated `scope.colorVar` with 'orange' but is don't reflect on UI, but `scope.exta` do reflect on UI.

http://jsfiddle.net/ut7628d7/1/

Any idea what am I doing wrong. and why this is happening and how to achieve it  ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether you want the directive's updated value to also change the original value in the controller or not:

#### Modify the original variable

If you want the directive to modify the original colorName in the controller, pass colorName by reference and use a two-way binding in the template:

```
<my-directive color='colorName'> <!-- instead of color='{{colorName}}' -->
```

and in the directive:

```
scope: {
    colorVar: '=color' // instead of '@color'
},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9szjpx9d/

The output from this will be "orange orange kk" because it's the same object throughout, so when the directive changes it to 'orange' it will affect both places.

#### Copy the variable

If you want the directive to only modify its own value, and output "red orange kk", then keep an attribute binding as you have now, but delay the directive link function by one tick using $timeout, so that the value it sets on scope will overwrite the value received via the directive attribute:

```
$timeout(function() {
  scope.colorVar = 'orange';
  scope.extra = 'kk';
});
```

Meanwhile the separate original color value will remain untouched in the controller, because it was passed to the directive as a string rather than as an object reference.

http://jsfiddle.net/mpb2cuaj/

Comment: thanks Daniel for your detailed answer. I am new to angular and was not aware of $timeout behavior, "Copy the variable"  is the thing I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change the color form inside your directive then use a two way binding. e.g.

```
scope: {
    colorVar: '=color'
}
```

HTML

```
<my-directive color='colorName'></my-directive>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0he428hw/